# Magento 2 - Check if attribute has value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, attributes

I try to display two custom attributes in the product view page but this attributes is not exist for all products. How I can check if current product contain one of this two attributes?

I use this code to get the attributes value:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('data_sheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('health_sheet')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 
    $dataSheet = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDataSheet(), 'data_sheet'); 
    $healthSheet = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getHealthSheet(), 'health_sheet'); 
    if(isset($dataSheet) || isset($healthSheet)){
        //display your DIV
    }
?>
```

Comment: but I have two attributes, I need to check if one of this two attributes have values. For example first can have and the second not, in this case I still need to display the entire div ...

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: is not work, I don't see any values when I try to echo that attrbutes

Comment: In which file you are try to print the attribute?

Comment: in this Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Comment: Please check that you are getting `$_product` object or not. if not then try `$block->getProduct()` instead of `$_product`